# python3.x : getting nothing output for a sequence in a series

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is the question which i am trying to solve is,

> what comes next after 2,3,10,15,26,35,50, ?

Actually the sequence is like this:

```
1*1+1=2
2*2-1=3
3*3+1=10
4*4-1=15
5*5+1=26
6*6-1=35
7*7+1=50
So next sequence will be-
8*8-1=63
```

I am trying to solve this in pythonic way but i'm getting nothing output as expected:

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))

def solve_problem(n):
    for x in range(n):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return (lambda x: x**2-1)
        else:
            return (lambda x: x**2+1)

solve_problem(n)
```

It would be great if anybody could figure me out where i'm doing thing wrong. thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `lambda`?

Comment: i basically used lambda to return the value as an anonymously and treated them as a variable. however below answer solved my problem as return the value with no arguments and simply print the variable. @CoryNezin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no print() in your code...you can start with this:

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))

def solve_problem(n):
    for x in range(1,n+1):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            print( x**2-1)
        else:
            print(x**2+1)

solve_problem(n)
```

And as another contributor asked, lambda may not be required here.